# Why are Terminal Alkynes less reactive than internal alkynes?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I got in Paula Bruice under the section **Mechanism for Mercuric ion catalysed Hydration of Alkyne**

> Terminal alkynes are less reactive than internal alkynes towards addition of water. Hydration will take place if Hg²+ is added to acidic mixture.

Why are Terminal Alkynes less reactive than internal alkynes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mechanism of hydration is an electrophilic addition and requires polarization of the carbon-carbon triple bond. This task is more difficult compared to case of alkene due to it having more %s character

In case of internal alkynes the carbocation intermediate formed ( since this mechanism is electrophilic addition the intermediate is a carbocation) is stabilized by the ***hyperconjugative effect and the inductive effect of the alpha carbons***.

***This support is taken away in case of terminal alkynes as their is no alpha-carbon***. Now terminal alkynes can still be hydrated but only in presence of $\ce{Hg^2+}$ ion in acidic medium because of $\ce{Hg^2+}$'s high polarizing power(because it has a pseudo inert configuration). This polarization succeeds in catalyzing the reaction.

**Ref.**: Morrison and Boyd, sec 12.10 (hydration of alkynes)